# error when edditing big text file using awk

Tags: awk

I have a text file like the following small example:

```
chr1    HAVANA  transcript  12010   13670   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.4"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "pseudogene"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; tr
anscript_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-001"; level 2; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_tran
script "OTTHUMT00000002844.2";
chr2    HAVANA  exon    12010   12057   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.4"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "pseudogene"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript
_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-001"; exon_number 1; exon_id "ENSE00001948541.1"; level 2; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; havana_gene
 "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002844.2";
chr3    HAVANA  exon    12179   12227   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.4"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "pseudogene"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript
_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-001"; exon_number 2; exon_id "ENSE00001671638.2"; level 2; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; havana_gene
 "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002844.2";
```

in the file there are different lines. each line starts with `chr`. every line has some columns and separators are either tab or ";". 
I want to make a new file from this one in which there would be a change only in columns 4 and 5. in fact column 4 in the new file would be `((column 4 in original file)-12)` and 5th column in the new file would be `((column 4 in original file)+50)`. I tried to do that in `awk` using the following command:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="\t;" } {print  $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4=$4-12"\t"$5=$4+50"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$9" "$10";"$11" "$12";"$13" "$14";"$15" "$16";"$17" "$18";"$19" "$20";"$21" "$22";"$23" "$24";"$25" "$26";"$27" "$28";"$29" "$30";"$31" "$32";"$33" "$34";"$35" "$36";"$37" "$38";" }' input.txt > test2.txt
```

when I run the code, it would return this error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN { FS="\t;" } {print  $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4=$4-12"\t"$5=$4+50"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$9" "$10";"$11" "$12";"$13" "$14";"$15" "$16";"$17" "$18";"$19" "$20";"$21" "$22";"$23" "$24";"$25" "$26";"$27" "$28";"$29" "$30";"$31" "$32 ";" $33" "$34";"$35" "$36";"$37" "$38";" }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN { FS="\t;" } {print  $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4=$4-12"\t"$5=$4+50"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$9" "$10";"$11" "$12";"$13" "$14";"$15" "$16";"$17" "$18";"$19" "$20";"$21" "$22";"$23" "$24";"$25" "$26";"$27" "$28";"$29" "$30";"$31" "$32 ";" $33" "$34";"$35" "$36";"$37" "$38";" }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ^ syntax error
```

do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Just wondering, did you delete your original question?

Comment: If the input is truly tab separated, then $9 should already contain all the `name "value";` pairs

Answer (score 0):

What you basically do is:

```
awk '{print $1=$1+2 ";" $2=$1+2}' < input
```

What you need to do is:

```
awk '{print ($1=$1+2) ";" ($2=$1+2)}' < input
```

^^^ Note that you need to parenthesize your inline assignments.

Or just do the assignments before printing:

```
awk '{$1=$1+2;$2=$1+2;print ... }' < input
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
awk ' {print $1 "\t" $2"\t"$3"\t"($4 - 12)"\t" ($5 + 50)"\t" $6 "\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$9"\t"$10"\t"$11"\t"$12"\t"$13"\t"$14"\t"$15"\t"$16"\t"$17"\t"$18""$19" "$20""$21" "$22";"$23" "$24""$25" "$26""$27" "$28""$29" "$30""$31" "$32""$33" "$34""$35" "$36""$37" "$38""  }' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: did you try this answer?