# modifying the text file in awk

Tags: awk

I have a text file like the following small example:

```
chr1    HAVANA  transcript  12010   13670   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.4"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "pseudogene"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; tr
anscript_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-001"; level 2; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_tran
script "OTTHUMT00000002844.2";
chr2    HAVANA  exon    53  955 .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.4"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "pseudogene"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript
_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-001"; exon_number 1; exon_id "ENSE00001948541.1"; level 2; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; havana_gene
 "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002844.2";
```

the expected output for the small example is:

```
chr1    HAVANA  transcript  11998   12060   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.4"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "pseudogene"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; tr
anscript_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-001"; level 2; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_tran
script "OTTHUMT00000002844.2";
chr2    HAVANA  exon    41  103 .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.4"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "pseudogene"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript
_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-001"; exon_number 1; exon_id "ENSE00001948541.1"; level 2; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; havana_gene
 "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002844.2";
```

in the input file, there are different lines. each line starts with `chr`. every line has some columns and separators are either tab or ";". 
I want to make a new file from this one in which there would be a change only in columns 4 and 5. in fact column 4 in the new file would be `((column 4 in original file)-12)` and 5th column in the new file would be `((column 4 in original file)+50)`. the only difference between input file and output file in the numbers in 4th and 5th column.
I tried to do that in `awk` using the following command:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="\t;" } {print  $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4=$4-12"\t"$5=$4+50"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$9" "$10";"$11" "$12";"$13" "$14";"$15" "$16";"$17" "$18";"$19" "$20";"$21" "$22";"$23" "$24";"$25" "$26";"$27" "$28";"$29" "$30";"$31" "$32";"$33" "$34";"$35" "$36";"$37" "$38";" }' input.txt > test2.txt
```

when I run the code, it would return this error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN { FS="\t;" } {print  $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4=$4-12"\t"$5=$4+50"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$9" "$10";"$11" "$12";"$13" "$14";"$15" "$16";"$17" "$18";"$19" "$20";"$21" "$22";"$23" "$24";"$25" "$26";"$27" "$28";"$29" "$30";"$31" "$32 ";" $33" "$34";"$35" "$36";"$37" "$38";" }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN { FS="\t;" } {print  $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4=$4-12"\t"$5=$4+50"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$9" "$10";"$11" "$12";"$13" "$14";"$15" "$16";"$17" "$18";"$19" "$20";"$21" "$22";"$23" "$24";"$25" "$26";"$27" "$28";"$29" "$30";"$31" "$32 ";" $33" "$34";"$35" "$36";"$37" "$38";" }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ^ syntax error
```

do you know how to fix it? I want to get the an output file with exactly the same format as input file. meaning the same delimiters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error when edditing big text file using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50249612/error-when-edditing-big-text-file-using-awk)

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to output every single column individually, it's enough to modify the existing data and then print the modified line.

```
awk -F '\t' '{ col4 = $4; $4 = col4 - 12; $5 = col4 + 50; print }' OFS='\t' file
```

This modifies the fourth and fifth tab-delimited column before printing the whole line.